# ’s apostrophe usage in "RNA’s"

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, acronyms

The following is a test of mba entrance

[image]

Why is there a `'s` after `RNA` in number 2 ?

PS: the number 2 should change to

> RNA's direct

according to the answer sheet.

Comment: This type of question has been asked many a time https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural+acronyms

Comment: so you mean that ** 's ** in RNA is suppose to make it plural?

Comment: Yep, you got it. To show plurality, some speakers use an apostrophe with acronyms and some don't.

Comment: i thought it suppose to show  possession but i couldn't find the other noun for it.

Comment: you may write it as an answer i'll give you a thumb up